# How to add margin in forms in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Is there any way to add margin between forms in django admin panel, because my admin panel looks so cramped without any margin i can control
[image]

Comment: This is not the regular admin to me, did you zoom out or something ?

Comment: no i don't zoom at all. it's 100% zoom in chrome, i'll add the modification in my admin.py file in the post

Comment: Your models.py or admin are not relevant, your design is not correct, you either modify the CSS or forgot to run the collectstatic, try ``django manage.py collectstatic`` and clear the cache of your browser